Is there any particular reason why I need a multiset for persistence barcodes? Can I define a barcode this way instead?
I've been reading the introductory paper written by these UPenn reseachers on topological data analysis, and in particular I've been focused on their section of persistent homology. To round things out, I read the Wikipedia article on persistent homology, but I found it's definition on the Persistence barcode difficult to read, and I was skeptical of the article's need to include multisets.
I was wondering if this alternate definition of a barcode would be sufficient:

$K$ is a simplicial complex. Have $I \subseteq 2^\mathbb R$ contain all connected intervals on the real number line, along with the empty set $\varnothing$. Fix some $n$, and have $\mathfrak K^n$ be the family of all n-dimensional subsimplices of $K$.
For each sufficient real-valued map $f : K \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that induces a filtration, have a barcode $B_f : \mathfrak K^n \rightarrow I$ where for some subsimplex $k \in \mathfrak K^n$, we have $B_f(k)$ be a connected interval for any $k$ that has one cycle with a nonzero lifetime. Traditionally, we could write this as a half-open interval $$ B_f (k) = [\alpha, \beta)$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are values in the extended real number line that represent birth and death, respectively.
Otherwise, have $B_f(k) = \varnothing$ when $k$ has a trivial lifetime or has multiple cycles.
Now, if we want to graphically plot out the barcode, we can still draw a bar for each subsimplex, but we can also enumerate when needed if we want to draw each bar in some order, instead of pulling things out of a multiset. The subsimplices that map to $\varnothing$ are simply not drawn on the bar diagrams.

Is there anything wrong about this definition? Can it be modified without much sweat to have a correct definition? Is there any reason in particular why you normally need a multiset for this definition, or is it just convention? If anything, I would prefer viewing the barcode as a function instead of a multiset, as the definition by function seems to be a richer store of information compared to the lossy definition by multiset.

Can you define what $B_f(k)$ is more precisely?

@JHF What would you like to be defined more precisely? The image is any open, closed, or half-open interval in $\mathbb R$ that's connected, so long as $k$ is at some point a cavity (which means it's lifetime is non-trivial, that is greater than zero). If $k$ is never a cavity then it has a lifetime of zero, which means it maps to $\varnothing$. I can more precisely define $B_f (k)$ as being some interval $(a, b)$ where $a$ is the index of birth in the filtration and $b$ is the index of death in the filtration.

A general subset $k \in 2^K$ is not necessarily even a simplicial complex, so it doesn't make sense to talk about whether it is a cavity.  Even if it is, it might contain multiple "cavities", etc.

@JHF I apologize, I meant for $2^K$ to be the set of all subsimplices but didn’t define that. Regarding the second point, does it become well defined if we do something simple like map all subsimplices with multiple cycles in them to $\varnothing$, or some such?

Also fix a dimension for $K$, ie look at $K^1$ for the 1-simplices

Your reformulation is still not technically correct: a subset of simplices need not comprise a subcomplex.  Even fixing this, your definition still lacks some nice properties of the usual persistence barcode.  For one, you are essentially computing persistent homology on every subcomplex, which may be much more computationally intensive.  For another, you lose the identification of homologous cycles: the same homology class may be represented by different cycles that are supported on separate subcomplexes.

@JHF I re-read my definition. Where am I still mentioning subsets instead of subsimplices of a simplicial complex? I can’t find it. For the second point, I’m not considering computational time or complexity. For your third point: true, but if you want to do the required quotient then is it not possible to do the quotient on this initial function to construct a new final function? That is, perform the quotient on my ordered pairs?

Perhaps you would be interested in the concept of persistence modules?  By viewing the homology groups concretely as generated by cycles modulo boundaries (instead of as an abstract vector space), you would keep track of where each persistent homology class came from in geometry.  It would be hopeless to classify persistence modules with their bases, but barcodes are a complete invariant of a persistence module up to isomorphism, i.e., forgetting the bases.  If all you care about are shapes up to homotopy equivalence, then perhaps you should only care about persistence modules up to isomorphism.
The reason why most practitioners of TDA focus on barcodes is that it is an applied field, and one would ideally like to have a combinatorial description that can be easily processed by a computer and does not require encoding the original geometric object.  Keeping track of all the bases for the persistence modules may be too much, when all you want is to feed numbers into a neural network or generate pretty visualizations.  (On the other hand, it is sometimes important to know where a particular homology class came from, though most of the work in this area focused on finding "optimal" (co)cycle representatives.)
